# Add line breaks in large XML file in one line

Tags: xml, notepad++

I have a large XML file in one line.

How can I add a line break for each tag so that it is not in one line in my editor?

I am using notepad ++

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 50, accepted):

From the menu , go to

```
Plugins --> XML Tools --> Pretty Print
```

If you don't have the XML tools plugin installed, you can download it by clicking on

```
Plugins --> Show Plugin Manager
```

And choosing  XML Tools

Comment: For version 6.5 menu item that did what I need was "Pretty Print(XML Only - with line breaks)" for me. Excellent results btw, amazing plugin.

Comment: The issue is that NotePad++ is not able to open big xml in one line.. Here I am, waiting for 30min and my 93MB one-line file is still not open.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps that will be useful to someone:

> How can I add a line break for each tag so that it is not in one line in my editor?

To do that to several files, automatically, I use XmlLint:

`xmllint YOUR_FILE.xml --format`

XmlLint is available in the Kubuntu/Ubuntu packages, and also can be downloaded for several operating systems in:
ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/

Comment: `xmllint YOUR_FILE.xml --format > output_file_name.xml`. This worked for me

Answer (score 4):

instead of of doing this : Plugins --> XML Tools --> Pretty Print , you can use this  usefull shortcut  :   **Ctrl + Alt + shift + B**